# Redefining a method overrides previous redefinitions

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'm trying to redefine 2 methods in a `Bar` class using the following code:

```
private <T> Class<? extends T> replaceMethodInClass(final Class<T> subclass,
    final ClassFileLocator classFileLocator, final String methodName) {
  final Builder<? extends T> classBuilder =
      this.bytebuddy.redefine(subclass, classFileLocator);
  return classBuilder
      .method(ElementMatchers.named(methodName))
      .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(CustomInterceptor.class))
      .make()
      .load(ByteBuddyReplaceMethodInClassTest.class.getClassLoader(),
          ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent())
      .getLoaded();
}
```

where the `CustomInterceptor` class is as follow:

```
static class CustomInterceptor {
  public static String intercept() {
    return "Hello!";
  }
}
```

In my test, I do the following to redefine the `Bar#sayHello()` and `Bar#sayHelloAgain()` methods:

```
@Test
public void shouldReplaceTwoMethodsFromClass_instanciateAfterChanges()
    throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, Exception {
  // given
  replaceMethodInClass(Bar.class, ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.of(Bar.class.getClassLoader()),
      "sayHello");
  replaceMethodInClass(Bar.class, ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.of(Bar.class.getClassLoader()),
      "sayHelloAgain");
  // when
  final Bar instance = Bar.class.newInstance();
  final String hello = instance.sayHello();
  final String helloAgain = instance.sayHelloAgain();
  // then
  assertThat(hello).isEqualTo("Hello!");
  assertThat(helloAgain).isEqualTo("Hello!");
}
```

Note that I explicitly want to replace the methods one by one.
The test fails because the `hello` variable is `null` (that's the value returned by the `Bar#sayHello()` method in the `Bar` class), but the `helloAgain` variable is set to `Hello!`, as expected (the `CustomInterceptor` class was used). So it seems like the first method redefinition was erased when doing the second one.

Do you have any idea what happened and how I can keep the 2 method redefinitions while not loosing the first one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the `ClassFileLocator` you are using. You are using a class file locator that is querying a class loader. A class loader always returns the class file that was originally available from the class file and is not aware of any transformations.

If you want to retain the changes of your first transformation, you would need to build some form of memory into your class file locator to return  the changed class file. You can read the bytes generated by a transformation from `dynamicType.getBytes()`.

You can also look up a live class file using the Java instrumentation API by `ClassFileLocator.AgentBased` which does however require attaching a Java agent.

Comment: Thanks for you response, Rafael! So, in order to retain the previous change, can I use a ClassFileLocator based on a directory (ie: `new ClassFileLocator.ForFolder(this.classDir)`, in which I would save the class' bytecode each time a method is redefined ?

Comment: Yes, this is probably the most reliable approach.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I was able to do it like that and it works perfectly. Thanks again for your support, Rafael !